# Docker compose hangs on Ubuntu 18.04 after Ctrl+C

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> immediately after running `docker-compose run`, then:

Intermittently it will hang, ultimately reporting:

```
ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
```

And:

All subsequent `docker-compose` commands for that `docker-compose.yml` will do the same until I restart the host.

Answer (score 2):

I have a remedy which at least avoids having to restart the host:

The container which failed to shutdown correctly is left in the `Created` state. So long as there is at least one container in this state, then the `ERROR` will occur.

Attempting to interact with `Created` containers (e.g. using `docker rm`) also results in the `ERROR`.

I have been able to remove them by:

1. `sudo service docker stop` (which does succeed), then:
2. Observe a dangling `docker-containerd-shim` process (as seen with a `ps aux | grep docker`) and kill it with a `sudo kill -9`.
3. `sudo service docker start` (which does succeed), then:
4. Remove the offending containers with:

   ```
   docker rm $(docker ps --all -q -f status=created)
   ```